# JDK 9 jshell printf() special treatment?

Tags: java, printf, jshell

I've been looking into JDK9 and i noticed that in jshell you don't have to prefix **printf()** with **System.out.printf()** i.e you can write **printf("test")** but you can't write **println("test")**

[image]

Is this a feature of jshell only ? How you can achieve the same behaviour in an application ?

The following is the closest :

```
import static java.lang.System.out ;
out.println("test");
out.printf("test");
```

Comment: For the record, `printf` was [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43864201/6730571)

Comment: Dissapointed with the pace of innovation in java and the decision making in alot of areas of the language anyway printing is a basic and important functionality i dont understand why they removed it from the default import of the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iit looks like `printf` is a command in JShell but `println` is not (just like in bash shell). The `printf()` method used by `System.out` is not the same as the one jshell uses and therefore can't be statically imported in a java application.

Sources:

http://jakubdziworski.github.io/java/2016/07/31/jshell-getting-started-examples.html
https://jshelltutorial.com/jshells-printf-method/

Comment: Thanks for updating to show your usage. I have edited my answer, if it still doesn't make sense let me know and I will explain further.

Comment: I was also looking for some insights, on how it is achieved... Or it is just a feature of jshell

Comment: It is just a feature of jshell. Think of it as a function that is only available by using jshell, it just happens to have the same name as a Java method.

Comment: Found it https://youtu.be/jziVaht480w?t=18m29s From the creator of jshell, its a method that wraps the System.out.printf() to a local prinf() method which is imported implicitly when jshell starts...

Comment: Nice find! If my answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer. If not then please post your own answer, or update the question with anything else you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

In earlier versions of early access there was a predefined printf method that redirected to System.out.printf.  There were two problems with this: it isn't standard Java and, as pointed out in other answers, it was inconsistent in that print and println were not defined.

In the current early access and in what will ship, there are no print methods automatically defined. If you want this, start jshell with:

```
jshell --start DEFAULT --start PRINTING
```

Which will give you the complete set of print methods.

To answer the second part of the question, you can see the definitions of the redirection methods by using the /method command after starting as above.  Adding these to a class would give you access -- but that it pretty ugly.  Alternatively, you could make them public static methods in a class, and import them.

Comment: At least as of Java 18.0.1.1, you can drop `--start DEFAULT --start PRINTING`, since invoking `jshell` without those flags allows `System.out.println("hi")` and `System.out.printf("hi %s\n", "there")` to work as expected.