# jshell - unable to find printf

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

Why does my jshell instance (JDK Version 9-ea) unable to identify `printf()` statement ? Below is the error I observe,

```
jshell> printf("Print number one - %d",1)
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   method printf(java.lang.String,int)
|  printf("Print number one - %d",1)
|  ^----^
```

I am able to access printf, provided I specify it in a regular way.

```
jshell> System.out.printf("Print number one - %d",1)
Print number one - 1$1 ==> java.io.PrintStream@1efbd816
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An earlier version of JShell had a `printf` method pre-defined but it was removed from early access builds. You can of course define your own printf method:

```
jshell> void printf(String format, Object... args) { System.out.printf(format, args); }
```

Or you can get the printing methods that were in earlier builds back by starting JShell with:

```
jshell --start DEFAULT --start PRINTING
```

(If you use only `--start PRINTING` you won't get the default imports.)

For more information see bug [JDK-8172102](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8172102) in the Java bug database and changeset [b2e915d476be](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/langtools/rev/b2e915d476be) which implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

Java is an object-oriented language and you cannot call a non-static method without an object associated with this method. `printf` is a non-static method of the class `PrintStream` and you cannot call it without a `PrintStream` instance.

There are some `PrintStream` instances in the standard Java library like `System.out` and `System.err`, so you can call `System.out.printf()` or `System.err.printf()`, but plain `printf()` does not work because `jshell` does not know which object this `printf()` belongs to.

Comment: This would be true of Java in general but it isn't true of JShell. You can define a method without defining a class, and JShell used to define a printf method, although it's no longer defined by default.

Comment: @DavidConrad All methods defined in jshell are implicitly static. That's why you can call them without objects.

Comment: It's not about being able to call them without objects but to define them without an enclosing class. You can't have a method, even a static method, outside a class in Java. But presumably JShell has some default class that it makes them methods of.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, there is an implicit enclosing class in `jshell`. If you write `class A {}` in `jshell`, then `A.class.getEnclosingClass() != null` will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it *simply* work without *jshell*? This can't work like this, since there is no such method defined *outside* `PrintStream`.

You could define your own `printf` like this:

```
jshell> private  void printf(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
```

And later use it :

```
jshell> printf("test")
test
```

Comment: It used to work *within* JShell. That's not a very good `printf` method, either.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more convenient:

```
jshell> /set start -retain DEFAULT PRINTING
```

(Need to set this once. Next time you can simply start jshell without any argument). See [official jshell documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/scripts.htm#JSHEL-GUID-AC2A6582-6A9A-48B1-ABBF-4C9536CDFD07).